# C# Sending an HttpWebRequest without the servername

Tags: c#, redirect, header, httpwebrequest

Basically what I've been trying to do is download a file off a server. The server sends a redirect automatically which is fine, but through packet sniffing a program that does successfully download the file I've found that the Headers (for the second request) are:

```
GET /path/to/file.txt
...
Host: server.com
```

Rather than the current response being generated (what I thought was standard):

```
GET www.server.com/path/to/file.txt
```

Using the normal HttpWebRequest method results in a 500 server error, and I get exceptions thrown when trying to use just the relative path as one would expect.
Using AllowAutoRedirect does not work for this scenario as the cookies are not handled properly, but even if I handle it manually the same error occurs.

How does one go about doing this (preferably without sockets :D)?

Comment: The "standard" GET in the post looks broken, I do believe. [HTTP 1.1 *requires* the Host header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) -- and in that case the URI might as well be server-relative. The 302/303/307 can always bee handled manually if more control is needed.

Comment: what package are you using to to GET the file? HttpClient is available via NuGet and much easier to use than the System.Net classes

Comment: Thanks @pst, you're right the (what I thought was) standard request isn't right. The request generated by HttpWebRequest is sending the host, but still puts in in the GET line as above, is there a way to remove this? It's the only thing I see different between my request and the one that's working. I am manually dealing with the 300 requests, the one I'm dealing with sends a Location header back and I'm trying to use this for my next request (only because 2 cookies are sent from the server and my CookieContainer seems to only store one when I use AllowAutoRedirect)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm really not sure what you are asking, but you mentioned cookie troubles. As a total shot in the dark guess, are you setting the CookieContainer on your WebRequest?

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```

Comment: I gave this a shot but I found it was only carrying one of the cookies I wanted over. I disabled auto redirect so I can manually get the cookie and make another request, but it appears my requests aren't valid the second time. Basically what I need to know is how can I get my request look like the first example I showed rather than the second!